# What is this 1ft tall plant?

Tags: identification

This small plant is growing in my yard and I don't know what it is. It reminds me on cosmos in its young age, but probably it isn't. Do you know?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks a lot like a fern

Comment: It is of the same family of Cosmos, but there are many possibilities. Where do you live?